# The implement of "make-serializer" in SICP Section 3.4

Tags: scheme, sicp, serialization

In the book page 258, the authors implement `make-serializer` like this:

```
(define (make-serializer)
  (let ((mutex (make-mutex)))
    (lambda (p)
      (define (serialized-p . args)
        (mutex 'acquire)
        (let ((val (apply p args)))
          (mutex 'release)
          val))
      serialized-p)))
```

In the book, there is a segment

> Given a procedure p, the serializer returns a procedure that acquires the mutex, runs p, and then releases the mutex.

I have a question: why is `val` after `release`? I think `val` should be in the front of `mutex 'release`. Am I right?

Comment: You can find the code in http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp09/library/serial.scm

Comment: the *calculation* of value of `val` is already before the mutex release - it's in the lambda form's variable definition subform, the one for `val`, `((val (apply p args)))`. as soon as the value is calculated, mutex is released; then the saved value is returned. the point is to protect the _calculation_ of the value.

Answer (score 1):

The bodies of `let`, `define`, `lambda` and some other forms have implicit `begin`s around their bodies. So that one doesn't need to write the `begin` except when you need one that isn't in a location that is the direct child of one of those forms. For instance that code with `begin`s inserted looks like this:

```
(define (make-serializer)
  (begin
    (let ((mutex (make-mutex)))
      (begin
        (lambda (p)
          (begin
            (define (serialized-p . args)
              (begin
                (mutex 'acquire)
                (let ((val (apply p args)))
                  (begin
                    (mutex 'release)
                    val))))
            serialized-p))))))
```

The value of a `begin` form is the value of its last argument. If

```
(begin
  (mutex 'release)
  val)
```

Was

```
(begin
  val
  (mutex 'release))
```

Its value would be the value of `(mutex 'release)` rather than `val`. That is why `val` is after `(mutex 'release)`.

Comment: Thank you!                                                                                                But we are not talking about the same thing.I mean as the sequence of " 1、acquires the mutex-------2、runs p-------3、releases the mutex".          But what I get from the code in the book is "1、mutex 'acquire-------2、mutex 'release--------3、val",which means thesequence of "1、acquires the mutex-------2、releases the mutex-------3、runs p".They are not in the same sequence.

Comment: @WalterZhao The steps are [1] acquire mutex [2] calculate `val` [3] release mutex [4] "return" `val`. Because `val` is lexically scoped within `serialized-p`, nothing can happen to it after [3] and before [4].

Comment: @ben rudgers. You mean when val is associated with the expression " apply p args ",the p process is calculated.So val is just the value of the expression,and at last "val" just return a value rather than execute p. I get it! Thank you very much

Comment: @WalterZhao Yes. As you know, *acquiring* the mutex means that other parts of the concurrent system are blocked until it is released. Therefore, the mutex should be *released* as soon as possible.